# JQuery Sortable + Drag and Drop Upload

Tags: jquery, drag-and-drop, jquery-ui-sortable

I'm trying to implement a combination of jQuery sortable and drag and drop upload.  The basic layout is a grid of images/objects which are sorted using jQuery sortable.  I can rearrange the images in whatever order I want by dragging them.  At the same time, I can upload new images from my file system by dragging and dropping anywhere on the div containing the grid, and the image appears in the first position on the grid after it finishes uploading.  I now want to make it possible for a user to drag a file onto any place in the grid, and then have the uploaded image appear in that *specific* position on the grid (while rearranging the other images accordingly.)

I haven't found anything yet quite like this -- I've been wondering if I should use either the stop or receive events in Sortable, but I'm still unsure how to keep track of where the user is dropping file on the page.  Any help would be much appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: Now I'm looking for the same method, could you solved the problem?

Answer (score 0):

try and have a look at the jqueryui website http://jqueryui.com/sortable/ not sure if it has what you are looking for

Comment: Thanks, that's what I've been doing...the problem is that I can't seem to find any way for Sortable to keep track of a file from the file system that's being dragged/dropped onto the page (or where it's being dropped), rather than simply an object that already exists on the page.